# Слушатель окончания загрузки и прорисовки данных в WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

В `Android` приложении в `Activity` использую `WebView` для отображения статьи с сервера.

Хочу выводить, например, сообщение после полной прорисовки данных (текста и изображений) на экране.

Вот так выглядит `WebView`:

```
 WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    // Пробовал этот метод:
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            System.out.println("Progress = "+ progress);
        }
    });

    webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
            "",
            asHtmlPage(intent.getStringExtra("content")),
            "text/html",
            "utf-8",
            null
    );
```

С сервера беру только `body` статьи без скриптов и адаптирую к нужному мне формату так:

```
private String asHtmlPage(String body) {

    String textUpd = body.replaceAll("<img ", "<img onclick=\"myFunctionGet(this.src)\" ");

    String style = "<style>" +
            " body { margin: 0; padding: 16; font-family: sans-serif-light, sans-serif; word-wrap: break-word;}" +
            " P:first-letter {  margin-left: 20px;  } " +
            " img { margin-left: -16; margin-right: -16; display: inline; height: auto !important; max-width: 100vw; } " +
            "</style>";
    String meta = "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>";

    String myScript = "<script> function myFunctionGet(s) { android.getUri(s); } </script>";
    return "<html><head>" + style + meta + myScript + "</head><body>" + textUpd + "</body></html>";
}
```

Пробовал использовать:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
       System.out.println("Progress = "+ progress); // от 0 до 100
    }
});
```

Но на момент когда получаю 100% - картинки еще НЕ полностью прорисовались на экране.

Как можно отследить что статья полностью загрузилась и все элементы полностью отобразились на экране?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
   System.out.println("Progress = "+ progress); // от 0 до 100
   }
});
```

На данный код:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public void onPageFinished (WebView view, String url){
   // ваш код который должен выполниться после полной прогрузки страницы
}
```

Comment: Ваш метод сработал. Спасибо!